# why my rails page always show html heads?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

in my data_feed controller and bar action, there's only one line in bar.html.erb:

```
[1,2,3,4]
```

My expected output by requesting  http://localhost:3000/data_feed/bar is just one line I wrote above.

However, rails help me add some html heads into that page, as below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Guustock</title>
<link href="/assets/application.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/assets/charts.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/assets/data_feed.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="/assets/show.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="/assets/jquery.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/jquery_ujs.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/charts.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="/assets/data_feed.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/show.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/assets/application.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
<meta content="authenticity_token" name="csrf-param" />
<meta content="lhHWCW82xtqQ8fmgBZemDggL2DGJe+4chXM8MY1LKvs=" name="csrf-token" />
</head>
<body>
[1,2,3,4]
```

How can I avoid rails doing this?
Thanks!

Env:
linux mint 11.0
ruby 1.9.3 with rvm
rails 3.2.1

EDIT:

Actually I want to provide the json format data in this page as an ajax data source. So these heads will not helpful but break the data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're probably rendering within the layout (a view template, which lives in app/views/layouts/), which is the default. If you want to render an action without the layout, use something like

```
render :bar, :layout => false
```

in the appropriate action.

See also: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html

EDIT:

Please see the documentation linked above. For JSON rendering, you might use this directly from the controller:

```
render :json => @product
```

or in your case

```
render :json => [1,2,3,4]
```

You could also use JSON view templates (for which you'll need to render again). Using a bar.html.erb template for json is not only tricky as you noticed, it will also produce the wrong content type headers.